# Diferença entre não estar claro e a pessoa não saber responder

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, razões-fechamento

Acho que esta pergunta não deveria ser fechada: [Como criar gráfico de Agulhas no R?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31065/como-criar-gr%c3%a1fico-de-agulhas-no-r)

Ela é simples: como criar um gráfico de agulhas no R. Pode ser que a pessoa na verdade queira outra coisa (ou queira mais coisas) e esteja confundindo, mas a princípio a pergunta é "respondível".

Comment: Reabri a pergunta. Ela não está muito bem escrita, mas compreendo a situação.

Comment: @utluiz, concordo plenamente, está muito mal escrita, mas oe pessoal está começando a fechar perguntas muito precipitadamente.

Comment: Pois é, isso é comum em tópicos mais especializados. Mas para isso mesmo serve o meta, assim você manifesta o seu ponto de vista e quem fechou a pergunta também terá o direito fazer o mesmo ou rever sua posição. ;)

Comment: É isso mesmo! Eu fui um dos que votou precipitadamente pra fechar, mas depois tentei reabrir conforme seu comentário. Às vezes uma pergunta *parece* ter problemas independentemente do tópico específico, quando na verdade quem tem muita familiaridade com esse tópico não vê aquilo como problema. Também já passei por essa situação algumas vezes no SOen, com Prolog ([exemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15082256/520779)).

Comment: @mgibsonbr não vou negar que realmente a pergunta possa ter problemas, por exemplo, às vezes ele quer algo mais complexo do que um "needle plot", que se adeque ao problema dele especificamente. Entretanto, não dá pra prever de antemão, e fechar a pergunta assim, ainda mais sendo a primeira pergunta da pessoa, acho que é uma recepção muito áspera!

Comment: Antes de votar para fechar, todos deviam considerar tentar melhorar as perguntas. Concordo que muitos se precipitam.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli discordo que o pessoal está começando a fechar perguntas muito precipitadamente. Faz tempo que isto acontece :)

Comment: @CarlosCinelli Há algum tempo houve [uma discussão](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/537/215) a respeito de "fechar e depois reabrir" vs "esperar bastante pra fechar". Em geral eu espero, mas quando por qualquer razão opto por fechar, eu não voto e vou embora: mantenho a aba aberta pra acompanhar a evolução da mesma e agir de acordo. De todo modo, concordo que passa uma impressão ruim (não havia reparado que o usuário era novo), vou evitar fazer isso no futuro.

Comment: @mgibsonbr legal a discussão, sua resposta lá está bem em linha com o que penso.

Comment: Ops, eu também `[...] fui um dos que votou precipitadamente pra fechar`. Vacilei em julgar uma coisa que não conheço baseado em parâmetros do que conheço. Lição anotada. . . . E, sim, novos usuários merecem muito mais feedback e ações positivas do que algum macaco velho que posta "Não sei fazer isso, faz pra mim?".